# How do I match technology to wake on lan from other services and applications

Tags: networking, juju, maas

This is not a duplicate question, though it is closely related and I need more clarification. Just to be clear this is on 14.04, and verified with the reseller and manufacturer that all new devices are capable of sending WOL magic packets as well to receive them. [WOL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723172/what-tool-can-i-use-to-scan-a-network-and-test-wake-on-lan')

All of my nodes are connected to a router instead of a switch. The reason I did this was to make sure that the WOL 'Magic Packet' was enabled and worked. From my smartphone, I downloaded three random WOL applications and was able to wake all nodes from the smartphone.

Moving forward with the MAAS / Juju / Openstack installation MAAS couldn't power on the devices. (even with wakeonlan / etherwake and maas-test installed) Has there been any changes with the packages or something that I have missed with the MAAS installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you look the MAAS source tree under `etc/maas/templates/power/ether_wake.template` you'll notice that it calls `/usr/bin/wakeonlan` or `/usr/sbin/etherwake` with no parameters except the MAC address. That leaves a few possibilities about why it isn't working:

- The MAC address is not stored within MAAS in a format that the tool recognizes. (it needs to be `:`-separated, such as `00:01:02:03:04:05`.)
- The tool is attempting to send packets out, but permission is denied by the operating system. (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504452/node-in-maas-not-waking-up-on-lan), where someone suggests adding a line to /etc/sudoers.d)
- The tool is sending the packets out, but on a nonexistent or incorrect interface. (according to the manual page, `-i ifname` is used to specify the interface, with the default being `eth0`)

All that said, it seems that using Wake on LAN is not a recommended way to run MAAS. Obviously it can be done, but since Wake on LAN does not support powering down machines or checking a machine's power status, it cannot be seamlessly integrated into a server management solution like MAAS.

Furthermore, it worries me when you say "connected to a router instead of a switch". If there is a layer 3 hop between the MAAS server and the machines you want to power on with Wake on LAN, chances are, it will *not* work. Wake on LAN generally requires the node to be on the same layer 2 segment. (on the same switch or VLAN.) In other words, you must be able to send broadcast Ethernet packets from the MAAS controller to the node you wish to power on.

A better bet would be to use an IP addressable power switch, or a machine that includes a dedicated management controller, such as IPMI or AMT.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and allow me to add more information. Currently there is two routers in place. The first router handles all 192.168.1.x traffic and out to the internet. The second router does not have dhcp and addresses the 10.0.0.x network. The MAAS controller is connected to the 192.168.1.x and the 10.0.0.x ... From this point the nodes are connected to the 10.x router. Now i connect my phone to access the router and send out a WOL packet, and it powers on. If i send out a packet from MAAS over the 10.x network in any form or fashion they do not power on.

Comment: Additionally I had used this reference as well to attempt the WOL efforts and to no avail. http://askubuntu.com/questions/723172/what-tool-can-i-use-to-scan-a-network-and-test-wake-on-lan -- Now that 16.04 is fast approaching I would like to see what happens with the WOL. I have also petitioned for professional support services to resolve the problem as well. It is also worth mentioning that once the devices were verified that they would WOL then they were moved OFF the router and put onto a netgear switch.

Comment: Based on the information you provided in that first comment, I have a suspicion that if you swap the network interface cards you are connecting the MAAS controller to, it will start to work. (that's the theory in my third bullet; that the MAAS power template isn't specifying the interface, so the packet goes out to the wrong network.)

Comment: I will be making a new installation of MAAS and when i get to where I am enlisting nodes, ill keep you up to date on the command lines etc. By the way, the question you have a link to 'this question' was mine as well and it still never really solved the problem.

Comment: thank you for trying to help, though I'm still back at where I was before. Reading the directions for MAAS it doesn't say a IP addressable power switch is needed or a machine that includes a management controller. Canonical NEEDS to be ACCURATE in their documentation, as some of us will follow it to the letter. Thank you for your assistance it is appreciated.

Comment: I have given you the bounty points because your the only one that tied to help. Sadly this was marked for Canonical and for a more official response was needed. This question has been out here for a month.